# Excel conditional formatting right alignment with indent

Tags: excel

I am searching for a way to make conditional formatting on my crosstable. For some specific lines, I want that my content must be right-aligned.

E.g.
    My crosstable

```
column 1   |   column 2     |
0          |left-aligned
1          |   right-aligned|
0          |left-aligned
1          |   right-aligned|
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which specific lines? Whats the condition?

Comment: for line with column 1 =0 then left aligned, column 1=1 then right aligned. Note that it's a crosstable, so you cannot apply standard format in some cells. It will disappear when you refresh.

Comment: Would you be open yo VBA?

Answer (score 2):

No, finally I don't need to use VBA for this. I just added a conditional formatting with custom format, like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWML4.png

Steps : add conditional Formatting: if column D<>0 then use custom format
In Custom Format : put this code : ;;;* @_)

After I can hide column D to have a beautiful crosstable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditional formatting based on another cell, but I don't think alignment is something that can be set with conditional formatting.

Select column 2 (e.g. column B), and add a new conditional formatting rule:
`=$A1=1`

[image]